# Can the SpotifyLocalAPI communicate to spotify with out an internet connection. Can it also retrieve the saved playlists and play from them?

Tags: c#, spotify

I am currently using the API from 
https://github.com/JohnnyCrazy/SpotifyAPI-NET

I am working on making my own front end for Spotify to be played only offline from the saved songs.

It seems to work well to play pause and skip songs. When it is connected to the internet. It also displays the album art.

I am asking to see if anyone has successfully created a new front end from spotify / retrieved the saved songs from spotify without having to be connected to the internet?

I am asking because I am planning on running spotify on a carpc and would like to incorporate the controls into the GUI and not just switch to spotify application.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no *official* way to retrieve tracks and track-info while being offline. The only way to fetch a user's tracks is via the Web-API, which, obviously, only works with having internet access. The only option left is reverse engineering spotify's client, which would be a lot of work.

**Regarding SpotifyLocalAPI:**
The local API is a so called `web helper`. It exists so the browser can communicate with the client and pass specifc tracks (used by http://open.spotify.com/). Since it's only designed for passing tracks and displaying very basic player information, they never implemented a method for fetching offline tracks/playlists.
*Source: I wrote this wrapper*